# Calculation error in SELECT statement

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have an SQL I am trying to create in a `DatasetAdapter` it works to a certain point but I cant figure out to get the last bit working.

I have a Table(MainTable) with the following Fields: ID Name Image Area Mean

I want to calculation `ABS(Area-?) AS Cal1, ABS(Mean-?) AS Cal2 , Cal1+Cal2 As Cal3`

```
SELECT 
ID, Image, Name, Area, Mean, ABS(Area - ?) AS cal1, ABS(Mean - ?) AS cal2, Cal1+Cal2 AS cal3
FROM  MainTable
```

I Then want to get the maximum value of Cal3

```
SELECT        MAX(cal3) AS maxofcal3
FROM          
  (SELECT        ID, Image, Name, Area, Mean, ABS(Area - ?) AS cal1, ABS(Mean - ?) AS cal2, derivedtbl_1.cal1 + derivedtbl_1.cal2 AS cal3
FROM            MainTable) 
derivedtbl_1
```

It works so far giving me the maximum value of cal3.

QUESTION:
I want to carry out another calculation ( Cal3/maxofcal3). I cant figure it out. I tried code below but came up with an error:

```
SELECT        MAX(Cal3) AS maxofCal3, Cal3 / MaxofCal3 AS Norm
FROM            (SELECT        ID, Image, Name, Area, Mean, ABS(Area - ?) AS cal1, ABS(Mean - ?) AS cal2, derivedtbl_1.cal1 + derivedtbl_1.cal2 AS cal3
                                                    derivedtbl_1.Cal1 + derivedtbl_1.Cal2 AS Cal3
                          FROM            MainTable) derivedtbl_1
GROUP BY Cal3 / MaxofCal3.
```

Answer (score 1):

Group by Cal4 only, not by Cal4 / MaxofCal4

Check the following example to get the idea how to make your code work:

```
CREATE TABLE #SampleTable (ID int, Image nvarchar(10), Name nvarchar(10), Area int, Mean int )


SELECT MAX(Cal3) AS maxofCal3, Cal4 / MAX(Cal3) AS Norm
FROM (
SELECT ID, Image, Name, Area, Mean, ABS(Area - 1) AS cal1, ABS(Mean - 1) AS cal2, ABS(Area - 1) + ABS(Area - 1) AS cal3, ABS(Area - 1) + ABS(Area - 1) AS Cal4 FROM #SampleTable
) derivedtbl_1 
GROUP BY Cal4


DROP TABLE #SampleTable
```